# Find the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$, if we know that $\lvert G\rvert=6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Today I've been looking the third Sylow theorem. My professor did an example in class, so I tried to solve the example by myself and then compare what I did with the answer of my professor. The exercise is this:

> Let $G$ be a group, and $\lvert G\rvert=6$. Find the number of Sylow $2$-subgroups and Sylow $3$-subgroups.

This is my solution:

> We see that $\lvert G\rvert=6=2\cdot 3.$ Let:
>   \begin{equation}
> \begin{cases}
> n_2=\text{number of Sylow $2$-subgroups}\\
> n_3=\text{number of Sylow $3$-subgroups}
> \end{cases}
> \end{equation}
>   By the third Sylow theorem, we know that:
>   \begin{equation}
> \begin{cases}
> n_2 \mid 3\ \ \text{and}\ \ n_2\equiv 1\ \ \text{(mod}\ 2)\\
> n_3 \mid 2\ \ \text{and}\ \ n_3\equiv 1\ \ \text{(mod}\ 3)\\
> \end{cases},
> \end{equation}
>   so
>   \begin{equation}
> \begin{cases}
> n_2=1\ \text{or}\ 3\\
> n_3=1\\
> \end{cases}
> \end{equation}

But my professor wrote this:

> \begin{equation}
> \begin{cases}
> n_2=1\\
> n_3=1\ \text{or}\ 3\\
> \end{cases}
> \end{equation}
>   And we see that
>   \begin{equation}
> n_3=
> \begin{cases}
> 1\to \text{This Sylow $3$-subgroup is normal}\\
> 3\to \text{Those three subgroups are conjugate between them}
> \end{cases}
> \end{equation}

I don't see why he says that $n_3=1$ or $n_3=3$. By the third Sylow theorem, the only possibility that I see for $n_3$ is $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're absolutely right that $n_{3} = 1$.

It's $n_{2}$ that can be either $1$ (in a cyclic group) or $3$ (in $S_{3}$).

Comment: How do you know that $n_2$ is $1$ in a cyclic group?

Comment: If $G = \langle g \rangle$ is a cyclic group of order $n$, and $m \mid n$, one can show that $\langle g^{n/m} \rangle$ is the unique subgroup of $G$ of order $m$.

Comment: It looks like your professor just accidentally mixed up $n_2$ and $n_3$.